# create control dynamically vs drag and drop

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++

Are there any differences as far as performance, memory usage, etc. between creating controls (picturebox, button, textbox, etc.) by drag and drop into the form vs created it dynamically in code for ASP.NET in C# or C++?  Which method is preferred by the pro?

Comment: I believe dynamic creation is more expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally professionals design the Forms by writing Code.
But the the control needed at runtime or compile time is really depends upon situation or need.So It is not having any performance aspects between these two approaches.

Generally beginners should design the form by daragging and dropping controls on the form , and should observe the generated code.

Comment: I like all the answers.  But this one where you said "and should observe the generated code."  I have the need to use both drag and drop and manually create control on the fly.  And by looking into the "generated code", I was able to understand how to ....

Answer (score 2):

When you drag-and-drop, Designer in Visual Studio actually generates code for you, so the performance is identical. I wouldn't recommend doing it dynamically unless you have the need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The "drag and drop" in Visual Studio just creates the code for you. The resulting executable is built out of the code, and the compiler does not care whether the code was written by you personally, by Visual Studio or by a trained monkey.

Yes, it's possible that the graphical designer in Visual Studio adds additional attributes to your HTML/ASP elements that you would not have added yourself, but I doubt that it makes a measurable difference w.r.t. performance.

Experienced developers usually like to either

- hand-craft their code or
- use the graphical designer and double-check the created code (the "split screen" view is very useful for that)

because unnecessary attributes make the code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Define "dynamically."

- If by "dynamically" you mean manually writing the markup and manually declaring the control and wiring up the events, then no there is no run-time performance difference.  Assuming you manually created things correctly, the compiled result is the same.  (It may even be possible to slightly improve performance by manually creating as little functionality as possible to get the job done, but this is rare because the compiler is pretty good at optimizing things.  I can't even really think of an example off the top of my head.)  But, essentially, manually creating the code and having Visual Studio create the code both produce the same output.
- If by "dynamically" you mean instantiating the control at run-time and wiring it up at run-time, etc. then you may incur a performance hit.  The framework is, again, pretty good at keeping things efficient.  If you get into reflection at all then you may slow things down a bit, though.  But in general there isn't really a significant hit unless you try to get really clever with your object creation or are talking about seriously high-activity sites where milliseconds add up fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference as far as memory or performance that I know of, but there ARE differences. For example, non-dynamic controls (the drag and drop you refer to) are instantiated in the Page.Init, whereas the controls you add dynamically may come from a button click, the Page.Load, etc.

Just be aware of the initialization differences, and also how the [ViewState is handled for dynamic controls](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addingcontrolstowebformspageprogrammatically.aspx).